# -SUID- Can't run a "-rwsr-xr-x" file as root

Tags: c, ubuntu, permissions, suid

I am using Ubuntu 16.10.

I was following along a book, doing something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Real UID:\t%d\n", getuid());
    printf("Effective UID:\t%d\n", geteuid());
}
```

And to run this file as sudo without using the sudo command, after compiling with gcc, I changed the owner and group to root.

```
$ gcc -o test test.c
$ sudo chown root:root ./test
$ chmod u+s ./test
$ ls -l
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 8512 Mar 9 test
```

Now, this is what I got when I executed the file. My UID is 1000.

```
$ ./test
Real UID:        1000
Effective UID:   1000
```

The book I was reading said the result should be like this:

```
$ ./test
Real UID:        1000
Effective UID:   0
```

The UID for root is 0, right? Does this mean that I am running an *-rwsr-xr-x* file, owned by root, with my own user privilege? I don't understand.

Comment: I wonder if this question might be better suited to the [Ubuntu SE site](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: @FredLarson You're right...

Answer (score 1):

Is your book a little on the older side? It seems like modern *nix variants widely ignore the sticky bit on executable files:

> [...] the Linux kernel ignores the sticky bit on files. [...] When the sticky bit is set on a directory, files in that directory may only be unlinked or renamed by root or the directory owner or the file owner.[4]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit

Comment: I'm not sure if a 2008 book is old, but I see that things don't work the same now as how it did when the book was written. The book is "Hacking: The art of exploration, 2nd Edition", by Jon Erickson, 2008.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's changed a little since then :) If my answer helped you, could you consider accepting it?